# SQL Server Hangs when creating view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

In SQL Server 2014 when creating a new view SQL Server management studio hangs for about 10 minutes then comes up with the error...

> failed to retrieve data for this request. An exception occurred while
>   executing a transact-SQL statement or batch. Lock request timeout
>   exceeded

We can then create and save a new view as normal. Any ideas why this is happening and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unlocking the database before creating your view:

First see if there are any exiting connections:

```
SELECT request_session_id
FROM   sys.dm_tran_locks
WHERE  resource_database_id = DB_ID('[dbname]')
```

If there are any open sessions, kill them using:

```
kill 52
```

Then use this to unlock the database:

```
USE [dbname]; 
ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Now you can create the view.

After that, don't forget to change the database to multi user mode:

```
ALTER DATABASE [dbname]
SET MULTI_USER
```

Comment: Bear in mind that ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE will prevent any current transactions from completing, and will roll them back. This is correct behaviour, but it needs noting.

Comment: I ran the above and now get the error Database is already open and can only have one user at a time, will not let me create the view.

Comment: Thank You - I ran ALTER DATABASE [db] SET  MULTI_USER - Seems to be running alot quicker now.